# updating transactions with preaggregated data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transactions table. I need to update the table with a pre-aggregated value from another table and then roll these down to varying levels of granularity.

However, the final output is incorrect. Hoping someone here can help me figure out how to go about this.

```
Table A:

 TransID   BankName   Location   Region  SaleType  MonthlyPayment Weight

   1        BOA        Boston     East    F          3000           3
   2        Mellon     Pittsburgh East    C          1000           3
   3        BOA        Boston     East    C          2000           2
   4        BOA        Boston     East               1000           2


 Table B

  BanKname   Location      Region   Sales
  BOA         Boston        East     500
  Mellon      Pittsburgh    East     1000


  Desired Output structure

  BankName    Location   Region   SaleType  AvgSales  AvgMonthlyPayment
```

Issue is that when updating and doing the weighted average, each of the Boston transactions is getting the 500 sales. When added, total sales should be 1500 but is now 2500.

If I update Table A with Sales value from Table B, sales gets repeated for each saletype - so it throws off the final average sales.

```
  update is this: (Added new column sales in A)

    update a
    set a.sales = b.sales
    from tableA a join tableB b on a.bankname=b.bankname and 
    a.location=b.location and a.region = b.region


    weighted average from A is calculated like this:

     select bankname,location,region,saletype, 
     sum(case when sales is not null then sales*weight else 0 
     end)/sum(weight) as avgsales
     , sum(case when monthlypayment is not null then monthlypayment*weight 
     else 0 end)/sum(weight) as avgmonthlyp
     from tableA
     group by bankname,location,region,saletype
```

For each saletype, the sales is updated with value thus increasing the final value by that fold.

How can I update sales so that BOA only gets 500 and Mellon only gets 1000 and the total # sales is at 1500?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: Problem is: if I update table A with the sales from Table B, each row in Table A gets the sales due to different saletypes - thus throwing off the final sales value when its weighted average is calculated. So question is how do I update the txns table with this aggregated value without losing the integrity of the data

Comment: You need to get the sales for the different sales types and it seems like you can't move further without that since your weighted average requires to multiply sales by weight and weight differs with sales type.

Comment: And thats where the problem is, I dont have sales by different sale types - i only have aggregated sales. Hence the question here.

Comment: You can't multiply sales by weight without knowing the sales for different sales type. So you can't proceed further with what you have right now.

Comment: IF i didnt need to do a weighted average of sales, but did a sum(sales) - i would still not be able to apply it correctly since sales will be repeated for each saletype resulting in incorrect total sales. Is there any other way for this scenario?

Comment: You can use average since every row will be getting the same sales for a specific bank and getting the average of those would solve the issue.

Comment: Your join is causing duplication so it is probably not a valid join